# The best config for LNMP on Centos7.0 with 0.5G memory

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, mariadb, vps

I run a shodowsocks and a wordpress on my vps .

VPS Config

> Centos7.0 with 0.5G memory + 1 CPU

Server

> PHP 5.4.16 + Nginx 1.6.3+MariaDB 5.5.44

But my MariaDB always to die,and when i start MariaBD

> systemctl start mariadb

result

```
> Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Run

> systemctl status mariadb.service

result

```
> mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 三 2015-11-11 00:42:58 EST; 14s ago
  Process: 10969 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10968 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10941 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10968 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
11月 11 00:42:57 jack mysqld_safe[10968]: 151111 00:42:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/jack.err'.
11月 11 00:42:57 jack mysqld_safe[10968]: 151111 00:42:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
11月 11 00:42:57 jack mysqld_safe[10968]: 151111 00:42:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/jack.pid ended
11月 11 00:42:58 jack systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
11月 11 00:42:58 jack systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
11月 11 00:42:58 jack systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
```

Run

> journalctl -xn

result

```
> -- Logs begin at 日 2015-11-08 06:23:57 EST, end at 三 2015-11-11 00:42:58 EST. --
11月 11 00:27:21 jack sshd[10936]: Failed password for invalid user pi from 104.233.81.149 port 53083 ssh2
11月 11 00:27:21 jack sshd[10936]: Received disconnect from 104.233.81.149: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
11月 11 00:40:43 jack kernel: Ack 2451881106 before 2451884026:2451898626
11月 11 00:42:57 jack systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
11月 11 00:42:57 jack mysqld_safe[10968]: 151111 00:42:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/jack.err'.
11月 11 00:42:57 jack mysqld_safe[10968]: 151111 00:42:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
11月 11 00:42:57 jack mysqld_safe[10968]: 151111 00:42:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/jack.pid ended
11月 11 00:42:58 jack systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
11月 11 00:42:58 jack systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- The result is failed.
11月 11 00:42:58 jack systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
```

I don't know how to  optimize my config, and i use my-small.cnf for MariaDB.
Is there a best config for my vps,thanks a lot.

Comment: Is that the contents of mysqld.err ?  Do you have anything other than mariadb running in that time VPS?  What are the values for *buffer* in /etc/my.cnf?

Comment: I run the nginx+php+mariadb in my VPS.Then i use my-small.cnf as the my.cnf,it worked fine. Thank you very mush.